# Modx Revolution SlideshowManager - list all albums

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to list all albums that are available in the SlideshowManager Addon in a TV List.

To do so I am trying to make a snippet for that like it is described here https://github.com/jgulledge19/Slideshowmanager/blob/master/core/components/slideshowmanager/processors/mgr/album/getlist.php

But I don't get any results. Here is what I have so far.

The TV

```
@eval return $modx->runSnippet('jgSlideshowAlbum__getList',array());
```

My Snippet

```
<?php
// create query
$query = $modx->newQuery('jgSlideshowAlbum');
// $query->limit(10);
$query->where(array('title:=' => 'Main Slideshow'));
// get albums
$albums = $modx->getIterator('jgSlideshowAlbum',$query);
// return result as list
foreach($albums as $album) {
die(print_r($album->toArray()));
}
```

For the moment I just want some output so I die() if there was found something.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Here the output of the Errorlog

```
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class 
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class !
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class jgSlideshowAlbum
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:53:28] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) ::getSelectColumns() is not a valid static method.
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class 
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class !
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class jgSlideshowAlbum
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:35] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) ::getSelectColumns() is not a valid static method.
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class 
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class !
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class jgSlideshowAlbum
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:54:54] (ERROR @ /index.php) ::getSelectColumns() is not a valid static method.
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class 
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class !
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class jgSlideshowAlbum
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) Could not load class: jgSlideshowAlbum from mysql.jgslideshowalbum.
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) No class specified for loadClass
[2014-03-18 11:56:11] (ERROR @ /index.php) ::getSelectColumns() is not a valid static method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to call the original processor in your snippet?

```
<?php

$limit = 0;
$sort = 'id';
$dir = 'ASC';
$query = '';

$properties = array(
    "limit" => $limit,
    "sort" => $sort,
    "dir" => $dir,
    "query" => $query
);

$slideshowmanagerPath = $modx->getOption('slideshowmanager.core_path',null,$modx->getOption('core_path').'components/slideshowmanager/');

$modx->addPackage('slideshowmanager',$slideshowmanagerPath.'model/');

$otherProps = array(
    'processors_path' => $slideshowmanagerPath . 'processors/'
);

$response = $modx->runProcessor('mgr/album/getlist', $properties, $otherProps);
$albums = $modx->fromJSON($response->response);

$output = '';
foreach($albums['results'] as $album) {
    if (!empty($output)) $output .= '||';
    $output .= $album['title'] .'=='.$album['id'];
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yeah that would be nice :) ... but your code gives me back some strange output that I don't understand. How can I now get the values? $response->get('title') for example didn't work :/ I need It in the format "title==album_id||next_title==next_album_id" to make a list of it.

Comment: Sry, had no time. In the list there are some entries like this "). [tv_type] => Eingabetyp [tv_value_inherited] => Wert geerbt [type] => Typ [uncategorized] => unkategorisiert [undelete] => Wiederherstellen [undeleted] => Nicht gelöscht [unpublish] => Zurückziehen [unpublish_date] => Zurückziehungs-Datum [unpublish_events] => Zurückziehungs-Ereignisse [unpublished] => ..." and so on ;)

Comment: can you show output snippet, if you just call it on resource?

Comment: Sry, didn't thought at this possibility :) I will do so as soon as i come home.

Comment: If I call the Snippet in the Frontend it doesn't give an output back. What is strange. But I added the errorlog to my question. The Class is not found if I call it in the Frontend nor in the Backend.

Comment: I made changes to the snippet in my answer, you can try it in work.